# necesito Ayuda con el diseño de un elemento para un RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-listview, cardview

Tengo Problemas con el diseño del elemento de un `RecyclerView`. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Mi problema es que cuando tengo el elemento "listo" al momento de ejecutar el modelo en mi celular, sale todo descuadrado... y no sé por qué.

Tengo este diseño como elemento de mi RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ilPubs"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPubImagen"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_patita"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPubNombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nombre"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/LoginCen">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Animal:"
                    android:textSize="17sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Edad:"
                    android:textSize="17sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tamaño:"
                    android:textSize="17sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Color:"
                    android:textSize="17sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Perro"
                    android:textSize="17sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPubEdad"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3 Años"
                    android:textSize="17sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPubTamanio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Grande"
                    android:textSize="17sp"/><TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Negro"
                android:textSize="17sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

la imagen se vería así en el diseño de mi android studio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de ejecutarlo en mi celular se ve de esta forma...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé qué puede estar pasando :( este es mi código del .xml del activity que contiene el RecycleView:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.danie.adopet.Activities.Principal"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_principal"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Publicaciones"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPubs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Les dejo mi clase Adaptador y la manera en que conecto desde la actividad;

ADAPTADOR:

```
public class AdaptadorRecycle extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorRecycle.ViewHolderPubs> {
ArrayList<PublicacionBO> lstPubs;

public AdaptadorRecycle(ArrayList<PublicacionBO> lstPubs) {
    this.lstPubs = lstPubs;
}

@Override
public ViewHolderPubs onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_pubs,null,false);
    return new ViewHolderPubs(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderPubs holder, int position) {
    //Llenar nos datos!!
    holder.tvNombre.setText(lstPubs.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.tvEdad.setText(lstPubs.get(position).getEdad());
    holder.tvTamanio.setText(lstPubs.get(position).getTamanio());
    try {
        holder.img.setImageBitmap(new UsuarioDAO().getFotoPerfilBitmap(lstPubs.get(position).getImagen()));
    }catch (NullPointerException e){}

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lstPubs.size();
}

public class ViewHolderPubs extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView img;
    TextView tvNombre,tvRaza,tvColor,tvTamanio,tvTipoAnimal,tvEdad,tvDescripcion;

    public ViewHolderPubs(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPubImagen);
        tvTipoAnimal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPubTipo);
        tvNombre= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPubNombre);
        tvEdad = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPubEdad);
        tvTamanio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPubTamanio);
        tvColor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPubColo);
    }
}
```

}

Integración de los elementos a la actividad Principal:

```
RecyclerView rvPubs;
    ArrayList<PublicacionBO> lstAnimales;

    rvPubs = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvPubs);
    //Llenar la lista
    lstAnimales = new PublicacionDAO().ListarbyArray(db);
    rvPubs.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rvPubs.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    //Asignar adaptador con valores a la lista
    AdaptadorRecycle adaptadorRecycle = new AdaptadorRecycle(lstAnimales);
    rvPubs.setAdapter(adaptadorRecycle);
```

Practicamente eso sería todo, no sé cómo hacer para que la vista del elemento del RecycleView se vea como está en el diseño del android studio :(

Gracias por su tiempo y espero que me puedan :)

Comment: En el 5* y 6* `LinearLayout` de tu adaptador cambia el `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` por un `match_parent`

Comment: Ya encontré la solución!! pero antes... Hice lo que me dijiste iuninefrendor pero me daba el mismo error. Justo ahora acabo de cambiar el ManagerLayout, de LinearLayaoutManager a un GridLayaoutManager con 1 de spanCount y ya me lo puso tal cual está en el diseño!!

Comment: @DanBer porque cambiarlo a GridLayoutManager no deseas se muestren en modo listado?

Comment: @DanBer te recomiendo no cambies de Manager, te sugiero mejor definir la propiedad de ancho como MATCH_PARENT al crear los RecyclerViews, esto en el método onCreateViewHolder(), agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Esto que comentas es un "problema" común cuando usamos `RecyclerView`, en este caso debes definir en el `RecyclerView` la propiedade `MATCH_PARENT` como ancho, esto se puede definir en el método `onCreateViewHolder()`:

```
@Override
public ViewHolderPubs onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_pubs,null,false);

/*------- Definir propiedad MATCH_PARENT en ancho------------*/
RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
view.setLayoutParams(lp);
/*-------------------*/

    return new ViewHolderPubs(view);
}
```